# How to select rows according to the frequency of elements in columns

Tags: text-processing

I have a file, as you can see, which is tab-separated data, about 4,000 lines, ten columns.

The second column of the file records the different tissues.

```
samples tissue_s tissue_e tissue_d tissue_category tissue_visa sex study tissue_f age
samples1  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples2  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples3  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples4  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples5  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples6  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples7  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples8  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples9  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
...
...
```

I hope to be able to print out all the information of tissues that have appeared more than ten times

But I think it is inefficient to do this and generate intermediate files. Is there a more concise and efficient method?

```
cat file | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > 10){print i}}}' > tmp.txt
grep -wFf tmp.txt file.txt > resule.txt
```

Comment: You describe the data as tab-separated. Are all column elements otherwise devoid of intervening whitespace? Or might an individual column contain separate words, such as `nasal septum` or `basal ganglia` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to process the input file twice:

```
awk -F'\t' -v frq=10 -v colId=2 '
  NR==FNR{ count[$colId]++; next }
  count[$colId] >frq
' infile infile
```

Note: User defined awk variables `frq` and `colId` are used for setting and to specifying at what minimum frequency of repeating the elements in the target columnId the records should be outputted.

---

Another way is to process the input file *once* and only *buffer few lines* at a time if your ipnut data is sorted on the 2<sup>nd</sup> field as following:

```
awk -F'\t' -v frq=10 -v colId=2 '
function prnt() { if(c>frq) printf("%s", buf); buf=c="" }

prev!=$colId{ prnt() }
{ c++; prev=$colId; buf = buf $0 ORS }

END{ prnt() }' infile
```

if it's not sorted on the 2<sup>nd</sup> field, so sort it first then pass it to the awk.

```
<infile sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 |
awk -F'\t' -v frq=10 -v colId=2 '
function prnt() { if(c>frq) printf("%s", buf); buf=c="" }

prev!=$colId{ prnt() }
{ c++; prev=$colId; buf = buf $0 ORS }

END{ prnt() }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my %h; do for lines.skip() {%h.push: .words.[1] => .words}; \
            for %h.kv -> $k,@v {(put $k; .put for @v) if @v.elems > 4};'  file
```

You might be interested in trying a Perl-family language, namely Raku. One advantage is high-level support for Unicode built-in, should you be exchanging data with colleagues using different language collations.

Above, a `%h` hash is declared, and auto-chomped `lines` (`skip`ping the header line) are `push`ed onto it, with `.words.[1]` (second column) as key and `.words` (all columns) as value. Since no duplicate keys can exist in `%h` hash, lines are added under each individual tissues found in the second column. Once all lines are processed, the hash is `%h.kv` key-value processed into a scalar `$k` key and `@a` values-within-an-array. Only `@v.elems > 4` are printed (i.e. more than 4 lines of the OP's Sample Input).

Sample Input:

```
samples tissue_s tissue_e tissue_d tissue_category tissue_visa sex study tissue_f age
samples1  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples2  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples3  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples4  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples5  ear     CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples6  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples7  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples8  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
samples9  stomach CNS      ear       CNS            CNS        male  1   ear 365
```

Sample Output (from the code above):

```
ear
samples1 ear CNS ear CNS CNS male 1 ear 365
samples2 ear CNS ear CNS CNS male 1 ear 365
samples3 ear CNS ear CNS CNS male 1 ear 365
samples4 ear CNS ear CNS CNS male 1 ear 365
samples5 ear CNS ear CNS CNS male 1 ear 365
```

It's fairly easy to adjust the output to suit your needs. Drop the call to `put $k;` if you don't want a separate "tissue" headerline. Additionally, change the `@a` lines output to `.join("\t").put for @v` to re-constitute `\t` tab-separated lines.

Note the answer above assumes each column entry is devoid of whitespace, since `.words` splits on whitespace (`\t` or not). If you can't guarantee that each column entry is a single whitespace-separated element, then use `.split("\t")` instead. Putting it all together (gives same output as above but now tab-separated):

```
~$ raku -e 'my \%h; do for lines.skip() {\%h.push: .split("\t").[1] => .split("\t")}; \
            for \%h.kv -> $k,@v {($k.put; .join("\t").put for @v) if @v.elems > 4};'  file
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org